# Change UIView height and subviews y position [Swift]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using auto layout to center my primary UIView horizontally and vertically. What I'm trying to do is animate the height from 363 to 182 while the subview which has a height of 182 pushes from its current offset to a y offset of 0.

In slightly less confusing terminology:
The goal is to have the subview towards the bottom, slide over the content at the top of the parent view while the parent view changes its height to the height of the subview.

Changing one before the other seems to break it either way. My last resort option is to have a view under the subview, that matches the background color of the controller to hide the fact that the parent view doesn't resize, but I'm using a corner radius so it would be kinda ugly that way.

I somewhat new to this whole auto layout thing so I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have a height constraint on the parent and a top constraint on the subview.

```
parentHeightConstraint.constant = 182
childTopConstraint.constant = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
    parentView.window?.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Ahhh so my issue is trying to change the views when I should be changing the constraints? Thanks for the quick response btw.

Comment: Yes, you need to modify the constraints, instead of directly setting frames. If you created the constraints in a storyboard, note that you can create outlets connected to the constraints you need to modify.

Comment: Ok awesome. Makes sense. Last question, will the parent be recentered again after it shrinks, or will the current top space stay as is? I'd want it to stay as is and just not be as tall since the purpose of this is to look nice when the keyboard appears. Thanks again.

Comment: It will be centered if that's what the constraints tell it to be. If you reset the constraint constants back where they started, the views will return to their original positions.

Comment: Worked perfect. I also added a top margin constraint of -= 91 to the animation to keep the top spacing position during/after the resize. Thanks again, you were a huge help :)